# bokeh server: callback execution order

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, callback, bokeh

On my bokeh server a time intensive calculation is done upon clicking a button. During the time of the calculation, i want to color the button to red and change the label to "Analysis in progress". This works well with below script on my laptop. **However exactly the same script does not work as excepted when i use a desktop i own as server. When running the script on that server first the calculation is done, and then for only an instant the button turns red and then immediately again green.**

The simplified script:

```
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import time

def callback():
    button.button_type="danger"#signal work in progress via the button style
    button.label="Analysis in progress, please wait.."

    time.sleep(3)#or do some computation that takes time

    button.button_type="success"#signal the analysis is done via the button style
    button.label="Analysis Done"

button = Button(label='Analyze',button_type="success", width=500)
button.on_click(callback)

curdoc().add_root(button)
```

My laptop:

- python 3.6
- bokeh 1.4.0
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1575M v5 3.00GHz,
  32.0GB RAM
- 64-bit Windows 10

My desktop:

- python 3.7
- bokeh 1.4.0
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2174G CPU @ 3.80GHz, 16.0GB RAM
- 64-bit Windows 10

I have tested in both Chrome, Edge and IE11. Also, when visiting the server on my desktop from my laptop, i notice the same issue. Hence i believe it is a server side issue.

Your hypothesis on this is appreciated, as well as alternatives on how to signal work-in-progress.

(you run the script in cmd by : `bokeh serve button.py --show`  )

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh depends on tornado. On both PC's the tornado version was different. Downgrading the tornado version from 6.0.2 to 5.0.2 solved the issue.

```
pip install tornado==5.0.2
```

Comment: It does appear earlier tornado versions behaved differently. However, you should expect that updates from callbacks are not sent *until the function ends*, and use the technique shown here if you need to "split" updates in one callback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196855/python-bokeh-markup-text-value-cant-update/59199773#59199773